# Option "always exit after closing last window" ignores Dialog Windows (exits even if dialog window is opened)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, exit

This is very annoying when some standalone GUI is created as Dialog Notebook. In that case I can't even open this application if this option is set.

How to reproduce (Mathematica 13.3):

0. Set option Preferences->Interface->"always stop after closing last window"
1. Create and save any dialog window:

```
nb = CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[{TextCell["Click OK to close"], DefaultButton[]}], 
  Saveable -> True];
NotebookSave[nb, FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "MyDialog.nb"}]];
```

2. Close all windows, then try to open saved file "MyDialog.nb" (using meny Open on Welcome screen) - it will open the document and then closes and quits Mathematica.